# What is the difference between Win 2k3 Server user CALs and Win 2k3 Terminal Server user CALs?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

[Here are 5 Server 2003 User CALs](http://www.royaldiscount.com/Windows+2003+Server+Ent+PG/Windows+Server+2003+5+User+CALs.html?osCsid=l79nojhu209qvembn57mkng5o7)

[Here are 5 Terminal Server 2003 User CALs](http://www.royaldiscount.com/Windows+2003+Terminal+Server/Windows+Terminal+Server+2003+5+User+CALs.html)

apart from the price disparity, what is the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Answer (score 4):

Server CALs allow users to connect to services (ex File Shares, Printers, IIS Sites).

TS CALs allow users to RDP into TS Sessions on the server.

Comment: but I can do file shares for free with any xp desktop, why would I need to buy licenses to share folders that are on a win 2k3 server?

Comment: XP Desktop is restricted to 10 concurrent users and has an extraordinarily limited set of file sharing capabilities compared to Server 2003 (which is also very limited compared to Server 2008 & R2).